# Label orientation in an R data.tree plot

Tags: r, plot, tree

Using the example from the plot.Node man page below, is it possible to change the direction of the labels in the nodes? By default they display horizontal and there doesn't appear to be any option to change the angle in the Style calls. Ideally I would like to display them at a chosen angle like 30 degrees but even a vertical orientation would serve the purpose.

```
library("data.tree")
data(acme)
SetGraphStyle(acme, rankdir = "TB")
SetEdgeStyle(acme, arrowhead = "vee", color = "blue", penwidth = 2)
#per default, Node style attributes will be inherited:
SetNodeStyle(acme, style = "filled,rounded", shape = "box", fillcolor = "GreenYellow", 
             fontname = "helvetica", tooltip = GetDefaultTooltip)
SetNodeStyle(acme$IT, fillcolor = "LightBlue", penwidth = "5px")
#inheritance can be avoided:
SetNodeStyle(acme$Accounting, inherit = FALSE, fillcolor = "Thistle", 
             fontcolor = "Firebrick", tooltip = "This is the accounting department")
SetEdgeStyle(acme$Research$`New Labs`, 
             color = "red", 
             label = "Focus!", 
             penwidth = 3, 
             fontcolor = "red")
#use Do to set style on specific nodes:
Do(acme$leaves, function(node) SetNodeStyle(node, shape = "egg"))
plot(acme)
```

[image: Program Output]

Comment: This page does not list a `rotation` or `orientation` attribute in its list of "all node attributes": http://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/ndfs_edfs.html . I get the idea that `node.js` documents would be the place to search for the more arcane aspects of what might be possible,

Comment: @42 The help page allows for other arguments to be passed into the SetNodeStyle call as follows:   ... 
For the SetStyle methods, this can be any stlyeName / value pair. See http://graphviz.org/Documentation.php for details. For the plot.Node generic method, this is not used. The graphviz documentation lists labelangle as a valid parameter but using it int the call has no effect. My apologies for the poor formatting here -- I am not familiar with the markdown for comments.

Comment: The table I found regarding `labelangle` indicated that it was to be used for edges but not nodes: http://graphviz.org/content/attrs#alabelangle

Comment: You are right. I missed the "Used By" column.